# Matpotlib: graph a function of 2 variables like (√︁x2 + y2)for (x, y)

Tags: python

Graph a function of two variables: Plot the graph of cos(√︁x2 + y2) for (x, y) ∈ [−5, 5] × [−5, 5].
Can you please help me with this task?

Comment: Help is a collaborative effort. Show where you have specific difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `matplotlib` library and its implicit function plotting tools, please visit the official [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/) for more information:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 3000)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 3000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
F = np.cos(np.sqrt(2*X) + Y**2)  #cos(√︁x2 + y2)

l = 5
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.xlim([-l,l])
plt.ylim([-l,l])
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Graph a function of one variable: Plot the graph of sin(x) for x in the interval
[0, 10]. Can you also help with this task?

Comment: @nurbike Yes, you can take a look at the documentation of matplotlib or ask another question on this site. Also, you can give feedback to this answer to help improve this community.

Comment: can you like answer to it here?

Comment: @nurbike i wold prefer to add more details in a new answer